# Send failure notification only for a scheduled execution

Tags: monitoring, rundeck, notifications

In Rundeck, how can job failure notifications be sent only for a scheduled executions, not for manually triggered ones?

As manual executions are normally monitored specifically by the person running them, so we don't want the failure e-mail list members receiving notices they should not be paying attention to.

The "by user" string in the e-mail doesn't help, because it seems to be the last user that has modified the job, not the one that has run the execution (where something like "Rundeck scheduler" could've been listed).